# How to receive new public ETH address for each user web3js?

Tags: web3js, ether

I would like to make a ETH payment gateway for my app. But i want each user after press payment receive a new address but still linked to my main wallet. How is it possible to give a random public address to users to make payment ?

```
Main purpose is to stay untraceable as a owner wallet
```

Comment: it is the nature of ethereum account that by default a new account is created with some random private key. So you just need to call the method that creates the account and it will be created with random private key

Comment: No no the purpose is to give random public key for payment but still linked to main public address

Comment: ok, got you. The only way would be creating a contract that would forward any deposit to your EOA. So for any user you would deploy a new contract. That will be costly , considering that contracts are large binary objects. However you can write some optimal version in assembly to just do the transfer on first instruction

Comment: you won't be untreacable, blockchain is a public system and everyone would know that your EOA received the money from the contract

Comment: So having just a static address would be good?

Comment: @Nulik Since all wallet will be the same a cheaper alternative is to use a [minimal proxy](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167). Still HD wallets seems a better option to avoid deploying a contract.